# Twilio Recording Ongoing call

Tags: twilio-api

I have to achieve below functionality using twilio recording and gathering API. I am struggling to achieve the exact goal can any one please help.

Steps :
1 - Agent will be on an existing call with customer.
2 - Agent dial twilio number for recording twilio should ask verification code.
3 - Agent will merge the existing call with twilio call.
4 - Agent will enter verification code.
5 - Twilio should accept call if verification code is valid and start recording existing merge call.
6 - Agent will stop call as soon as agent stops/disconnects call recording will be received by callback from twilio.

I am trying to initiate call using `twilio` call forward with security code when there is ongoing call between two cells..  e.g. I am dialing +91976693XXXX from my cell +91866835XXXX and we both on call.. Then we are dialing the twilio number "+1 813-501-XXXX " added webhook which returning the response Twiml :

```
<Response>
<Gather action='http://example.com/Modules/DisputeSuite/Customers/ValidatePin.aspx' numDigits='4'>
<Say>Please enter valid pin.</Say>
</Gather>
</Response>  on Action page if pin is correct i am sending response Twiml to initiate call : <Response>
<Dial record='record-from-ringing-dual' recordingStatusCallback='http://example.com/Modules/DisputeSuite/Customers/ConferenceResponce.aspx'><Number>+91976693XXXX</Number></Dial>
</Response>
```

All is working fine if i enter pin and then merge the call. But if i merge call first and then trying to enter pin then  is not forwarding pin to action page. Please help to resolve the issue.   Thank you